# libclang: how to get compiler macro definitions

Tags: c++, libclang

With clang LibTooling API one can get a list of compiler predefines simply using `clang::Preprocessor::getPredefines()`, but I cannot find any equivalent in libclang API. Is it possible to get a list of compiler predefines with libclang API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could list all predefines using the fact that they are present in the beginning of a translation unit. So after parsing I just listed all top-level cursors of `CursorKind.MACRO_DEFINITION` that are not in any real location (`cursor.location.file is None` using python bindings API)